# How can i write return on submit in active form in codeigniter?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to use   `onsubmit="return travel_form(this);`
 in active form

```
 <?php echo form_open_multipart('employee/travel/store_travel' ,['id'=>'abc']); ?>
```

How to use it. Please guide me.

Answer (score 2):

You can do with this :

```
<?php  array('onsubmit' => "return travel_form(this)"); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another way.

```
<?php $data = array('id'       =>  'abc', 
                    'onsubmit' =>  'return travel_form(this);');

echo form_open_multipart('employee/travel/store_travel' ,$data); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put it on your 2nd parameter which is the attribute

```
<?php 

     $attribute = array(
                    'id' => 'abc',
                    'onsubmit'  =>  'return travel_form(this)'
     );
     echo form_open_multipart('employee/travel/store_travel' , $attribute); 
?>
```